# A part of a model is corrupt

Tags: modeling

The 3D model I am using (Charizard) is slightly broken; notice on the left wing a portion of it is orange when it is supposed to be blue. Backface culling will not work, as it does not take effect in the actual animation. Doubles have been removed.

Any idea on how to fix it? Greatly appreciated.[image]

[model file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3KjFxxykagrUlQ2b21jSUtEckk/edit)

Comment: is it not possible to fix it manually (move vertices back )

Comment: do you try making the normals consistent??  select that face and  ctrl+n anc check inside

Comment: @Awsum can you upload this model to take a closer look

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3KjFxxykagrUlQ2b21jSUtEckk/edit

Comment: will this be enough  : [image with steps](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/87059)

Comment: @Chebhou Please write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A vertex from the wing is going throuhg the back , move this vertex forward and it'll fix :

[image]